# Have last static UITableViewCell fill screen (with MKMapView)

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, mkmapview

I have a UITableViewController in a iOS8 storyboard with a set of static cells. I would like to have the last cell fill the remaining space of the screen height. The last cell contains a MKMapView. How would you go about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured NOT using a UITableView was the best option in this case. I just had to figure out using autolayout and constraints properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a MKMapView Object with desired height(since different phones have different height), then assign it to [tableFooterView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableFooterView).